# how to display month using bootstrap date picker

Tags: datepicker

[I'm getting data in this format by implementing the below snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqL42.png).

I tried this:

```
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({

    format: 'dd MM yyyy'
 });
 $('#endDate').datetimepicker({

    format: 'dd MM yyyy',
     useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me

```js
$('#startDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DDMMMYY'
});
$('#endDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DDMMMYY',
    useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
});
```

in bootstrap 3 standard datepicker that I used. Here `MMM` is for three character abbreviated month and `MMMM` is for full abbreviation of month similarly `DD` is for 2 digit days with leading zeros and `YY` for 2 digit year with leading zeroes.